# Не могу залить таблицы в базу данных

Tags: mysql

Не могу залить таблицы в базу данных

SQL-запрос:

```
CREATE TABLE  `bomj` (

 `klu4` INT( 11 ) NOT NULL DEFAULT  '0',
 `night_act` TEXT NOT NULL ,
PRIMARY KEY (  `klu4` )
) TYPE = MYISAM ;
```

Ответ MySQL: Документация

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'TYPE=MyISAM' at line 5

Comment: Серьезно неделю??? УЖАС!!! Извините за сарказм :) Ответ ниже...

Comment: я очень усложняюсь все это понять так как я новичок, могли бы мы связаться ? если конечно вы поможите, вот мой скайп entera74  аська 363540383 почта entera91@gmail.com

Answer (score 3):

Так может все-таки не `TYPE = MyISAM`, а `ENGINE = MyISAM` ?
[Рабочий пример](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/dcb2c6) Ну а так как `MyISAM` и так по-умолчанию, то можете вообще явно не указывать `ENGINE = MyISAM`

Answer (score 0):

`klu4 INT( 11 ) NOT NULL DEFAULT  '0' и`PRIMARY KEY (  `klu4` )`- не совместимые понятия.`PRIMARY KEY`- означает что поле уникально! Поэтому`DEFAULT  '0'`- не может быть - ставьте`AUTO_INCREMENT`

Comment: Но SQL тем не менее никак не реагирует на эту ошибку, пока явно не попытаемся вставить данные с одинаковым первичным ключом в эту таблицу - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2fde0/1 Добавьте еще один INSERT без указания значения klu4

Comment: я очень усложняюсь все это понять так как я новичок, могли бы мы связаться ? если конечно вы поможите, вот мой скайп entera74  аська 363540383 почта entera91@gmail.com